# How to port forward to a specific application

Tags: networking, server, macbook-pro

On my lan I have a Ubuntu 20.04 server and a MacBook(OS:Monterey). When I enter in a browser on the Macbook, 192.168.X.XXX my Macbook goes straight to the Ubuntu machine. The Macbook browser shows the ip followed by '/' ie 192.168.X.XXX/ and it displays one of my apps, let's call it: APPLICATION ONE.  Great! Clearly the forward slash takes my browser to #ONE.

However, I want to access APPLICATION TWO from my Macbook.

How / what should I do to get the Ubuntu machine to go to #TWO, when I enter 192.168.X.XXX/applicationTwo? perhaps I need to modify the forward slash?? But how?

Many Thanks !

Comment: @user68186 That is the right answer.

Comment: Many thanks for that. I am using Apache -  do I do that through the virtual hosts?

Comment: Thank you - i have it working!

Comment: There is no need to thank me. I have converted my comments to an answer. Please accept the answer by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## This is not port forwarding, This is changing port

It looks like you have two browser based applications. Essentially they run 2 web servers.

The "Application One" must be using port 80 (or 443), the default ports for web pages.

Your "application two" can't use these ports. You have to set up "application two" to use a different port, say 8080. Then on your mac enter `192.168.X.XXX:8080` to access your "application two."

Hope this helps